# Working SASS preprocessor by Node.js through Grunt

Tags: javascript, ruby, node.js, sass, gruntjs

I have D:/projectA

Gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

// Project configuration.
grunt.initConfig({

    //Read the package.json (optional)
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    // Metadata.
    meta: {
        basePath: '../',
        srcPath: '../',
        deployPath: '../'
    },

    banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> - v<%= pkg.version %> - ' +
            '<%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %>\n' +
            '* Copyright (c) <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy") %> ',

    // Task configuration.
    concat: {
        options: {
            stripBanners: true
        },
        dist: {
            src: ['<%= meta.srcPath %>engine/css/mycss1.css', '<%= meta.srcPath %>engine/css/mycss2.css'],
            dest: '<%= meta.deployPath %>engine/css/00myfinal.css'
        }
    },

    //the Sass Task 
    sass: {
        sass_my_files : {

            files : {
                //"the Destination " : " the source files"
                "../engine/css/mystyle3.css" : "../engine/css/mysass1.scss",
            },
            options : {
                "style":"compressed",
                "precision":"7"
            },
        },
    },

});

// These plugins provide necessary tasks.
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');

// Default task
grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat','sass']);

};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "Test-Project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.1.3"
  }
}
```

Ruby is installed on my 'Windows'.

Inserting following command:

```
npm install ruby-sass
```

I get everything done. But on running 'Grunt' command, I get error:

```
You need to have Ruby and Sass installed and in your path for this task to work.
```

Can someone tell why my console is showing error after it successfully runs the '***concat***' task, and showing error on the '***SASS***' task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `npm install -g ruby-sass`, which installs the ruby-sass gem globally in your environment variables. Then proceed.

I recommend using Gulp over Grunt. They are similar in function but I prefer Gulp due to it's pipeline assets. Worth learning for sure.